# convert a map[string]interface{} to JSON and same JSON to map[string]interface{} (preserve interface{} types)

Tags: go

I am putting structs names and types into a map, Marshal this map into a JSON and Unmarshal this JSON back into a map which I can extract the types of each struct the same as before.

Here is what tried:
1 - have predefined structs
2 - define a map[string]interface{}
3 - populate this map with the struct name as key and struct type as interface() value.
4 - Marshaled this map into a JSON.
5 - Define a new map[string]interface{}
6 - Unmarshal the JSON into this new map for later use in the program.
My hope is to preserve the the reflect types of the interface{} the same.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

// Gallery :
type Gallery struct {
    ID     int
    Name   string
    Images []Image
}

// Image :
type Image struct {
    Source string
    Height int
    Width  int
}

func main() {
    myMap := make(map[string]interface{})
    myMap["Gallery"] = Gallery{}

    // encode this map into JSON, jStr:
    jStr, err := json.Marshal(&myMap)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
        // print the JSON string, just for testing.
    fmt.Printf("jStr is: %v \n", string(jStr))

    // create a newMap and populate it with the JSON jStr
    newMap := make(map[string]interface{})
    err = json.Unmarshal(jStr, &newMap)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println()

    // iterate over myMap and inspect the reflect type of v
    for k, v := range myMap {
        fmt.Printf("myMap: k is: %v \t v is: %v \n", k, v) 
        fmt.Printf("myMap: reflect.TypeOf(v) is: %v \n", reflect.TypeOf(v).Kind())

    }
    fmt.Println()

    // iterate over newMap and inspect the reflect type of v
    for k, v := range newMap {
        fmt.Printf("newMap: k is: %v \t v is: %v \n", k, v) 
        fmt.Printf("newMap: reflect.TypeOf(v) is: %v \n", reflect.TypeOf(v).Kind())

    fmt.Println()
}
```

The reflect.TypeOf(v).Kind() for both maps should be struct. But it is not the case. for myMap, the Kind is struct (which is correct), but for newMap, the Kind is map which is NOT correct. What am I missing here. Here is the full code on play.golang.org:  https://play.golang.org/p/q8BBLlw3fMA

Comment: The JSON decoder has no knowledge of the types used to create the JSON.   Can you decode to `map[string]Gallery` or `struct { Gallery Gallery }` instead of  `map[string]interface{}`?

Comment: Well, both map[string]Gallery and struct {Gallery Gallery] will work if all types were defined as Gallery. The idea behind the map is to hold multiple struct names and their associated struct types. This is why I thought using an interface{} will become a place-holder for any struct type. Just to add: I will actually be entering values into a JSON file manually and then using this JSON to create a map and compare the struct name as key and associated type (entered as value in the map) against a user input. I basically need a way to pass name/value to the program via an external file, e.g. JSON

Comment: Your comment describes a map containing struct types.  Did you mean struct values?  Does a given key uniquely identify the desired type of the value?

Comment: By values, I mean entries into the map. I don't mean struct values. To clarify a map defined as map[string]interface{}: the key part of the map [string] will represent the name of the struct and the value part of the map interface{} will represent the the type of the struct. E.g. to add a struct Gallery to the map, I will define it as: type Gallery struct{}. then to put this in the map, it will be: myMap["Gallery"]=Gallery{}      I really don't need the values of the struct fields. I need just the struct names and its type.